# save() function Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, model, controller, save

I have found this function in the documentation from Zend, more specific in the Create model and Database Table section ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html ).

This is in the Application_Model_GuestbookMapper:

```
public function save(Application_Model_Guestbook $guestbook)
{
    $data = array(
        'email'   => $guestbook->getEmail(),
        'comment' => $guestbook->getComment(),
        'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );

    if (null === ($id = $guestbook->getId())) {
        unset($data['id']);
        $this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
    } else {
        $this->getDbTable()->update($data, array('id = ?' => $id));
    }
}
```

and now i would like to integrate this into my controller, but i have no idea how?

I created an instance of the mapper and tried to pass the info from my decoded json string to it, but I still get errors...:

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $mapper = new Application_Model_GuestbookMapper();
   $db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();

   $json = file_get_contents('http://data.appsforghent.be/poi/apotheken.json');
   $data = Zend_Json::decode($json);

   foreach($data['apotheken'] as $row)
   {
       $mapper->save();
   }
}
```

I know i have to pass the $data to the save() function but I have no idea how... The model won't fit the json-url, I just wanted to show how I retrieve and decode the json.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Great! but still can't load my data in my database... Now i get this error: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'long' cannot be null... Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on the contents of $row, you may have to normalize the data to make it fit the model.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to pass in to the $mapper->save(); is an instance of Application_Model_Guestbook. So hopefully you have a class Application_Model_Guestbook in which you define the possibility to set a data array as its attributes, for example like this:

```
class Application_Model_Guestbook {
  private $email,$comment,$created;
  public function __construct($data) {
   $this->email = $data['email'];
   // etc add other variables
  }
  public function getEmail() {
   return $this->email;
  }
}
```

Then to call that, use:

```
   foreach($data['apotheken'] as $row)
   {
       $guestbook = new Application_Model_Guestbook($row);
       $mapper->save($guestbook);
   }
```

I have not tested this specifically, but it should give you an idea of how to achieve what you want to do.